# Problema Algoritmo Búsqueda

Tags: c++, while, busqueda

El ejercicio es el siguiente:

```
#define M 2
#define N 2
typedef char cadena[30];

class cuatro {
cadena tabla[M][N];
public:
void cargar(); //Pondrá en cada elemento de la tabla una palabra leída desde teclado.
void encontrar(); //Pedirá una palabra por teclado y mostrará por pantalla si esa palabra está o no en la tabla y en qué fila y columna se encuentra
};
```

El problema me viene cuando implemento `void cuatro::encontrar`:

```
void cuatro::encontrar(){
    cadena buscado;
    int k = 0, l = 0;
    bool encontrado = false;
cout << "Introduzca la palabra a buscar: "; cin >> buscado;

while (!encontrado && k < M){
    while (!encontrado && l < N){
        if (strcmp(buscado,tabla[k][l]) == 0)
            encontrado = true;
        else
            k++;
    }
    l++;
}

if (encontrado == true)
    cout << "La palabra " << buscado << " esta en la tabla" << endl;
else
    cout << "La palabra " << buscado << " no esta en la tabla" << endl;
}
```

En teoría, el k++ y el l++ deberían de estar al revés, pero poniendolos al revés no me encuentra las dos últimas palabras. ¿A qué se debe?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu condicional `!encontrado &&`, analizalo bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este bucle anidado:

```
while (!encontrado && k < M){
    while (!encontrado && l < N){
        if (strcmp(buscado,tabla[k][l]) == 0)
            encontrado = true;
        else
            k++;
    }
    l++;
}
```

Tiene dos problemas:

1. El segundo bucle **no inicializa** `l`. El segundo bucle se ejecutará `M` veces y está claro que la primera vez, `l==0`, sin embargo, las siguientes ejecuciones empezarán con `l==N`, luego no realizará iteraciones.
2. Cada bucle modifica el índice equivocado. El primer bucle, que comprueba `k`, modifica la variable `l`, mientras que el segundo bucle comprueba `l` y modifica `k`.

Estos dos problemas serían más faciles de ver y corregir usando los bucles apropiados para la ocasión:

```
bool encontrado = false;
for( int k=0; k < M && !encontrado; ++k )
{
  for( int l=0; l < N && !encontrado; ++l )
  {
    encontrado = strcmp(buscado, tabla[k][l] == 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Entonces, ¿sería mejor inicializar los valores `k` y `l`dentro de los bucles en vez de inicializarlos antes y usando bucles `for` en vez de `while`? Así es como nos han enseñado en la universidad: `for` para recorrido y `while`para búsqueda

Comment: @Grefuwan `while` se suele utilizar cuando las iteraciones son indeterminadas, o cuando la colección puede sufrir cambios entre iteración e iteración. En tu caso la iteración no cumple esos requisitos porque **siempre** se mueve en el rango [0,M] o [0,N]